# React.js Docker - Module not found

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

#### Prerequisites

**Linux** 18.04

**create-react-app** 2.0

**docker** 19.09.0

Dockerfile

```
# base image
FROM node:9.6.1

# set working directory
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ADD package.json /package.json

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install --save --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@latest -g --silent

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  provisioning-app:
    container_name: prv-app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
```

#### Problem

Everything has been working just fine, but after installing a new package docker stopped working as expected. Every time I run `docker-compose up` it fails with 'Module not found' error.
While `npm start` works perfectly fine.
I've tried quite a few workarounds found on the web:

- restart PC
- delete node_modules folder and run `npm i` again
- different combinations of `npm install` / `--save` / including --save in Dockerfile

It just doesn't work and I can't handle it on my own. Any ideas why this might be happening?

#### Update

Weirdly, but this code works. I'm a rookie in Docker, so I have no clue what's the difference

```
docker run -it \
  -v ${PWD}:/usr/src/app \
  -v /usr/src/app/node_modules \
  -p 3000:3000 \
  --rm \
  prov-app
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Everything has been working just fine, but after installing a new
>   package docker stopped working as expected. Every time I run
>   docker-compose up it fails with 'Module not found' error.

You need to rebuild your image to have that package installed. `docker-compose build`, and then `docker-compose up`

EDIT

Based on your update, I realize that the problem is your old node_module volume persisted between builds. Try `docker-compose down -v` before `up`.

Comment: It is not a good idea to build and up container on every new package wich installed after first build.

Comment: I don't understand what you are suggesting

Comment: Neither did this one, doesn't woks as well

Comment: If you have db in the docker network you have to add data everytime. So in the  long term this is not very viable

Answer (score -2):

Instead of:

```
volumes:
  - '.:/usr/src/app'
  - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
```

Try:

```
volumes:
  - ./:/usr/src/app
  - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

Comment: Nope, that made no difference